# Gpg4win: Avoid passphrase prompt, in java code

Tags: java, ssis, gnupg

i have created a SSIS package, which is using a Execute Process task, Inside this task a batch file is getting executed. This batch file is executing a java CLass file. The java code reads PGP files from a directory, after that it imports private key and executes gpg filename.gpg command. On successful execution it gives a prompt to enter passphrase.

**gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import PrivateKey.gpg** 
**gpg filename.gpg**
**Prompt for passphrase**

what I want to achieve is to avoid this prompt, to automate decryption process in my java code. So is there exist a command through which I can enter passphrase without getting the prompt.

[Prompt Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Qam.png)

Here is my java code

```
private void decryptFiles(String encryptedFilePath, String keyFilePath){
    try{
        //location to encrypted gpg file
        File encryptedFileLocation = new File(encryptedFilePath);
        //location for key file that will be loaded
        File keyFileLocation = new File(keyFilePath);

        //changing dir and loading key
        String []cmd = {"gpg", "--allow-secret-key-import --import Key.gpg"};  

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = runtime.exec(cmd, null, keyFileLocation);

        AutoDecrypter decrypterObj = new AutoDecrypter();
        if(p!=null)
            decrypterObj.displayCommandPromptOutput(p);
        else 
            System.out.println("Unable to create Process");

        if(encryptedFileLocation.isDirectory()){
            //all file with gpg extension will be stored in this array
            File[] allGpgFiles = encryptedFileLocation.listFiles(decrypterObj.new GpgFileFilter());
            builder.directory(encryptedFileLocation);
            cmd = new String[2];

            cmd[0] = "gpg";
            for(File f : allGpgFiles){
                //taking feed files and decrypting them one by one
                String fileName = (f.getName()).substring(0,(f.getName()).length()-4);

                cmd[1] = "--output D:\\AutoDecrypt_Feeds\\feed\\"+f.getName()+" --passphrase 123 --symmetric D:\\AutoDecrypt_Feeds\\feed\\"+fileName;

                System.out.println((f.getName()).substring(0,(f.getName()).length()-4));
                builder.command(cmd);
                p = builder.start();

                decrypterObj.displayCommandPromptOutput(p);
                System.out.println("- Decrypted");  
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("Enter a directory!!");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private void displayCommandPromptOutput(Process p) throws IOException {
    //output of command prompt is displayed
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String cmdOutuptTxt = "";
    while((cmdOutuptTxt=bfr.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(cmdOutuptTxt);
    }
}

//to get only gpg files from any directory
class GpgFileFilter implements FilenameFilter{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
        return fileName.endsWith(".gpg");
    }  
}
```

this is what i tried, there is no error no prompt but it is not decrypting files
**cmd[0] = "gpg";

cmd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Qam.png) = "--output D:\AutoDecrypt_Feeds\feed\"+f.getName()+" --passphrase 123 --symmetric D:\AutoDecrypt_Feeds\feed\"+fileName;**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [options to specify a passphrase](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html#GPG-Esoteric-Options):

> --passphrase-file file
>
> Read the passphrase from file file. Only the first line will be read from file file. This can only be used if only
>   one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file
>   is of questionable security if other users can read this file. Don't
>   use this option if you can avoid it. Note that this passphrase is only
>   used if the option --batch has also been given. This is different from
>   GnuPG version 1.x.
>
> --passphrase string
>
> Use string as the passphrase. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this is of very
>   questionable security on a multi-user system. Don't use this option if
>   you can avoid it. Note that this passphrase is only used if the option
>   --batch has also been given. This is different from GnuPG version 1.x.

Or you could [generate a key without a passphrase](https://superuser.com/questions/861689/how-to-generate-a-gpg4win-keypair-without-passphrase).

Bear in mind these all have security implications, as noted in the documentation: if you're not very careful about what you're doing, it's basically the equivalent of storing the keys to your house under your doormat.